ONION / TOR / NodeJS / WebSocket error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
const wsUrl = 'ws://178.75.80.44';

Итак, когда у меня стоит IP в вебсокете - подключение через прокси сокс5 (onion/tor) происходит нормально, но когда я пытаюсь вместо IP использовать onion адрес, он не может подключиться и выдает такую ошибку.
WebSocket error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND a53neeeby74uyvyyslcsds73tv54ak6w24k5vubzif7f5uz3saijx4yd.onion
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'testeby74uyvyyslcsds73tv54ak6w24k5vubzif7f5uz3saijx.onion'
}

Код который я использую:
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const { SocksProxyAgent } = require('socks-proxy-agent');

// Создаем агент прокси SOCKS5
const proxyHost = '127.0.0.1';
const proxyPort = 9050;
const proxyAgent = new SocksProxyAgent(`socks5://${proxyHost}:${proxyPort}`);

// URL веб-сокет сервера
const wsUrl = 'ws://testeby74uyvyyslcsds73tv54ak6w24k5vubzif7f5uz3saijx.onion';

// Подключение к серверу через прокси
const ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl, { agent: proxyAgent });

// Обработчики событий веб-сокета
ws.on('open', function open() {
  console.log('Connected to the server');
  // Отправляем данные на сервер
  ws.send('Hello, server!');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(`Received: ${data}`);
});

ws.on('close', function close() {
  console.log('Disconnected from the server');
});

ws.on('error', function error(err) {
  console.error('WebSocket error:', err);
});

В ubuntu если я включаю вебсокет клиент таким образом torsocks node client.js - подключение происходит нормально и соединение есть к .onion серверу, но через прокси с обычным запуском он не может GetAddrInfo. Как быть, что сделать?
